# Handle Deserialization Exception in Formatter of Delegating Handler

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I'm using web API and implementing delegating handler.

I have a customization of Json serializer / deserializer which is registered as a formatter in the API configuration.

```
    var globalFormatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
    var jsonFormatter = globalFormatters.JsonFormatter;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(...)
```

As for exception handling, I've added an ExceptionFilterAttribute, and also added it as a filter in the configuration.

```
public class MethodAttributeExceptionHandling : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();

        var response = errorHandler.ProcessError(actionExecutedContext);

        actionExecutedContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```

This seemed to be working well, until I encountered a deserialization exception,
which did not get caught in my filter.

I've read the exception handling documentation [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling) which mentions serialization exception are not caught by the filter (It does not mention serialization however), and I couldn't find any solution to catch it and handle it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it will help someone else,

In order to deal with this issue I implemented an ActionFilterAttribute, where in my implementation of the OnActionExecuting I'm checking if the model state is invalid, and do error handling stuff if so.

That's the spot just before the action execution and after the object deserialization.

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Do error handling Stuff...
    }
}
```